# jQuery - show slider values in inputs

Tags: jquery, input, slider

how to show my slider values in inputs, so when user is dragging a slider - the values will be dynamically shown in the inputs next to each slider?

Here's example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YHmkp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).next().val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/YHmkp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the slider events as detailed on http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/:

eg:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) {

     // value is supplied in ui.value for single-handled sliders
     var currentValue = ui.value;

     $("#yourinputbox").val(currentValue);
   }
});
```